How can the gain of a TL431 + optocoupler be calculated?
I am studying one of Christophe Basso's publications, which is very helpful, but I don’t understand why only \$R_{LED}\$ appears in the denominator of the formula discussing the gain of the TL431 and the optocoupler.
Why is \$I_1=\frac {V_{OUT}}{R_{LED}} \$?
Why is the voltage drop across the TL431 catode and the LED diode \$0V\$?


He's on here as @verbal-kint.

Do you know what small-single analysis is? Simply, in small signal analysis, any ideal constant voltage is treated as a short circuit (no AC component across it).

Do you need more explanation?

If we consider the TL431 a perfect Zener diode when it regulates - otherwise stated the voltage at its cathode K is perfectly flat when you ac-modulate this circuit for analysis - then it's small-signal ac voltage is exactly 0 V: $\frac{dV_{K}}{dV_{out}}=0$. Therefore, if $V_{out}$ is modulated, it induces a current in the LED equal to $\frac{V_{out}}{r_d+R_{LED}}$ which is $\approx \frac{V_{out}}{R_{LED}}$ if we neglect the LED dynamic resistance $r_d$. $r_d$ has little impact if $R_{LED}$ is large but may influence the gain if $R_{LED}$ is small and a small FB current flows.

"Why is I1=VOUTRLED
? Why is the voltage drop across the TL431 catode and the LED diode 0V
?"
Because at high frequencies C1 (shown in the previous schematic below) and the negative feedback to the TL431 REF input generates an AC short.
But the value of C1 should be included in the feedback loop frequency response.


Love those bandpass glyphs...

But $C_1$ is connected to $R_{lower}$, not to $GND$. I don’t understand why the LED and the TL431 are being bypassed. It seems this is beyond my abilities. :D
I fully understand the transfer function. I also accept this, but I just don’t get it... :D

If you think in high frequency, where $C_1$ is a short circuit, what is ac the voltage at the TL431's cathode while you ac-modulate $V_{out}$? 0 V but that is an ac value, the dc point is still there but as $C_1$ is a short circuit, no ac signal goes through the TL431. So if you have 0 V in ac, then you see that $V_{out}$ splits between the LED resistance $R_{LED}$, the LED dynamic resistance $r_d$ in // with the bias resistance. But if you simplify the analysis by neglecting $r_d$ which is way smaller than $R_{LED}$ and $R_{bias}$ then you only consider $R_{LED}$.

I think I understand now! Thank you again for your help! Btw, $R_{lower}$ doesn’t matter because the TL431 shunts it from an AC perspective?

When C1 is a short circuit (at high frequencies) the ac source (Vout) is passed to TL431's cathode.  We are assuming the TL431 is an ideal zener diode with a perfectly flat curve and no dynamic resistance at ac.  No voltage is developed across it.  That's why it's 0 V.

If TL431 was considered non-ideal and had dynamic resistance then the ac current through C1 and the ac current through R_led would affect the voltage at the cathode.

When C1 is a short, R_lower is shorted to the cathode of the TL431.  The circuit is designed to operate the TL431 in Fixed Zener Mode at high frequencies using C1.  The voltage at R_lower is the voltage across the ideal Zener.  Which is 0V.

$R_{lower}$ does not play a role for $s$ different than 0 because you have a virtual ground. $C_1$ closes the loop but opens it in dc. Should you have an OTA instead, then $R_{lower}$ would play a role.

The key that's being missed here is that when C1 is shorted, the control input of the TL431 is shorted to the cathode.  This places the TL431 into Fixed Zener Mode.  From there we assume the Zener diode is ideal with a perfectly flat curve and no dynamic resistance.  Therefore no voltage is developed across the Zener due to ac current.  Therefore the ac voltage at the cathode is 0 V.
See Fixed Zener Mode under Applications
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL431

Thank you very much for the answer! I finally managed to understand how it works. :)
